# How do check the status of service in centOS 7 and 8 in JAVA without using command?

Tags: java, centos7, systemd, centos8, systemctl

Is there any way to check the service status in centOS 7 and 8 using java without using command?

I am **avoiding** java process class to run a command to check the service status as I have multiple services I need to check and from my tests, using the process to send a command is kinda slow, more than 1 second

I know that for network interface, you can read files like `/sys/class/net/enp0/operstate` or `/sys/class/net/enp0/carrier` to know if the interface is up or down. `carrier` indicate "1" or "0" and `operstate` indicate "up" or "down"

Is there something similar for services? or is there any better/faster way for java to check service status?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 9+, you can use [ProcessHandle.allProcesses()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html).

Otherwise, you can scan the [`/proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) hierarchy.